# How to load text in richtextbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, text, load

I have problem with loading text in richtextbox.I have the whole code built but I miss the last step. The text does not appear in the richtextbox but when I click ctrl+V the text appears. All count I would like tol oad without click. If the question has already been asked I am sorry.
Perhaps my question makes sense.
Thank everybody for all advice
Form1:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace projektadresar
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public static string folderPath = string.Empty;
    Form2 form2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form2 = new Form2();
    }

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FolderBrowserDialog folder = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        if (folder.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(folder.SelectedPath);
            textBox1.Text = folderPath;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        form2.Show();
        Visible = false;
    }      
}
}
```

form2:

```
 using System;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace projektadresar
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    
    
    public Form2()

    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static int GetFileCount()
    {
        var fileCount = 0;
        var fileIter = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Form1.folderPath);
        foreach (var file in fileIter)
            fileCount++;
        return fileCount;
    }
    public static int GetDirectoryCount()
    {
        var directoryCount = 0;
        var directoryIter = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(Form1.folderPath);
        foreach (var directory in directoryIter)
            directoryCount++;
        return directoryCount;
    }

    private void richTextBox1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        richTextBox1.Text = "Directories:" + GetDirectoryCount() + Environment.NewLine + "Files:" + GetFileCount();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hmpf, there is a lot going on here ... Without going to much in-depth, I think you should take the time and read about MVC and MVVM patterns and accordingly use a shared model in both Forms instead of referencing each other. Many such problems will then go away naturally.

Comment: Remove all reference of Form2 from Form1 and any reference of Form1 from Form2. Add a public property to Form2 (e.g., `public string FolderPath {get; set;}`). In `button2_Click`, add `var f2 = new form2(); form2.FolderPath = textBox1.Text; f2.Show();`. Now, in Form2, you can have: `var fileIter = Directory.EnumerateFiles(this.FolderPath);`. Form1 could subscribe to the `Form2.FormClosed` event to make itself visible when Form2 is closed.

Comment: _richTextBox1_Load_ there is no such event.

Comment: everything works but files counts wrong

Comment: `var directoryCount = Directory.GetDirectories(this.FolderPath).Length;` etc. (based on my previous comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't intertwine form 1 and form 2. All that Form1 should know about form2 is what information it needs to do its job.

Form 2 should not know who created it. It should trust its creator that it provides you with enough information.

Apparently form 2 needs a folder path of which some information should be shown. It might be that while form 2 is being shown, that the folder path changes. So whenever the folder paths is changed, the text should be updated automatically.

```
class Form2 : Form
{
    private DirectoryInfo folder;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // set by the creator of this form before the form is shown.
    // May be updated while the form is being shown:
    public DirectoryInfo Folder
    {
        get => this.folder.GetFullName();
        set
        {
           if (this.Folder.FullName != value.FullName)
           {
                this.folder = value;
                this.UpdateRichTextbox();
            }           
        }
    }

    private int FileCount => this.Folder.EnumerateFiles().Count();
    private int DirectoryCount => this.Folder.EnumerateDirectories().Count();

    // called when the form is has been loaded (subscribe to event!)
    private void OnFormLoaded(object sender, ...)
    {
        // this.folderPath should have been set, by the owner.
        // update the RichTextBox for the first time
        this.UpdateRichTextbox();
    }

    private void UpdateRichTextBox()
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = "Directories: " + DirectoryCount + Environment.NewLine
                          + "Files: " + FileCount;
    }
}
```

Form1:

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 form2 = null;

    private string FolderPath {get; set;}

    private void ShowForm2()
    {
        if (this.form2 != null)
        {
            // decide what to do if form2 already shown
        }
        else
        {
            this.form2 = new Form2
            {
                Folder = new DirectoryInfo(this.FolderPath),
            }
            this.form2 = Show(this); // I am the owner!
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ShowForm2();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to close Form2 when you close Form1 (event FormClosing).

Don't forget to dispose Form2 when you Dispose Form1